# I can't modify User model data in django

Tags: python, django

When I create a user with (from Shell):

```
u = User.objects.create_user('Angel', 'angel@test.com', 'angel')
```

If then I execute (in the shell):

```
u.first_name = 'Angel'
u.save
```

If I see the data base (MySql) I see that the first_name is empty.

Comment: In Python, methods are not automatically called when you name them. `u.save` is a bound method. It must be `u.save()` to call it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't call `save` (you forgot the parenthesis):

```
u.first_name = 'Angel'
u.save()
```

Comment: Thanks i forgot type the brackets. Thank you very much